# Keyboard problem, strange functioning

Tags: 14.04, keyboard, hardware, configuration, hp-pavilion

I've looked almost everywhere and I can't find a solution. I have a Hp Pavilion 15 Ubuntu 14.04.4 installed, the thins is I was writing a text document when suddenly s key started working as <kbd>F5</kbd>. Then I tried to fix it by changing and reinstalling keyboard layout but got worse. I tried some other solutions on internet but looks nothing works. To give you an idea of how its my keyboard working  .

<kbd>s</kbd> key works as <kbd>F5</kbd>
<kbd>d</kbd> as <kbd>F2</kbd>

There were another anomalies but now just <kbd>Fn</kbd> keys and <kbd>s</kbd> and <kbd>d</kbd> works for something. Sometimes starts typing <kbd>s</kbd> when I press

I would be eternally thankful with you if know the answer, I'm new at Linux systems. {I'm writting through Universal Access keyboard}

Answer (score 0):

This really sounds like a hardware problem.

What happens if you boot up a Live CD or USB stick and see if the problem persists (if you still have your LiveCD or USB stick you used to install)? That should give us a fairly clear idea of whether it's hardware or software/configuration.

Another thing you could also test, especially if you don't have a LiveCD or USB stick, is plugging in a second keyboard to the machine and seeing if the same problem happens on the external keyboard. If not, it's probably something with the internal keyboard on the laptop.

From the proximity of the keys that are misbehaving, it really sounds like some circuit in your keyboard hardware is getting shorted or not making contact. If that is the case, you should be able to get a new keyboard for the laptop. Many times, if you get the exact model of the laptop you can order a new keyboard part. If you look on the website of the manufacturer, they should have a manual for installing the new keyboard. Or a computer repair shop should be able to do that for you.

Comment: I've try to run the live usb but it did't worked because keyboard arrows weren't working. I've just bought an external keyboard and works properly so I conclude that the fail its in the internal keyboard circuits. I don't really know if a homemade repair its reliable (neither know how to do it)

Comment: Replacing the keyboard is the standard (reliable) way to fix this. If you don't feel comfortable doing it yourself, have a computer repair shop do it for you, or worse case, you could ship it to the manufacturer and have them do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

There are some problems with HP 15 keyboards working properly https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1532746) though your problem doesn't quite fit the pattern of those.  If it's still under warranty, I'd send it back to have the keyboard replaced.  If not, it's fairly simple (if tedious) to crack it open and check that the keyboard connector is secure.  An example video can be found at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EuovxquGRFk.  Search for your precise model if it looks significantly different.